# One matcher result to act as condition

Tags: java, android, split, find, match

I have a textbox which sends a string one either one or second form. if one matches it has to do something if second matches it has to do other thins if none matches it has to giver error. i have done it using two patterns and matches and i also know that i can put OR operator in pattern.compile to match them but how do i get like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("one|two"); //("one") if only one pattern
Matcher found = pattern.matcher(string);

if(found.find()==one)
//code
else if(found.find()==two
//code
else
//error
```

Comment: `find()` is not the same as `matches()`. For an input string like `Say "you're not alone" two times`, both `one` and `two` are present, so what do you expect from it?

Comment: You can use two different pattern matchers to accomplish this, first try with one Pattern and then with the other, if none matches show error.